# nullable environment variables in Symfony

Tags: symfony, environment-variables

I know that env variables are string only. Symfony 3.4 [supports env variables type casting](https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-3-4-advanced-environment-variables).
Is there a way to pass null value through int validator?

.env

```
DATABASE_PORT=
#I also tried DATABASE_PORT=null, DATABASE_PORT=~
```

parameters.yml

```
app.connection.port: '%env(int:DATABASE_PORT)%'
#I also tried env(?int, env(int?
```

I'm getting an error: "Non-numeric env var "DATABASE_PORT" cannot be cast to int." or "Invalid env(?int:DATABASE_PORT) name: only "word" characters are allowed."

In yml there are ~ or null signs used to pass null, e.g:

```
app.connection.port: ~
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Someone asked in the doc:

> Is it, or will it be possible to define your own operator? Like
>   `%env(myDecoder:API_PASSWORD)%`, which will decrypt the environment
>   value into something usable.

```
class MyDecoder implements EnvironmentOperator {
  public function resolve(string $value): string { 
    // magic stuff for decryption 
    return $value;
  }
}
```

And the answer was:

> yes, you just need to create a service that implements
>   `EnvProviderInterface` and tag it with `container.env_provider`.

You could create an operator to accept `null` as an `int`

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. I was thinking if it's already implemented by any chance.

Answer (score 1):

Try use fallback param:

```
app.connection.port: '%env(int:default::DATABASE_PORT)%'
```